# Codeigniter selecting a certain table from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I just want to ask if you can select a certain table in the database? There is this code in my

**model:**

```
public function select_tables(){
         $tables = $this->db->list_tables();
         return $tables;
     }
```

and in my **controller:**

```
public function maintenance(){
        $this->data['title'] = "Inventory Maintenance";
        $this->load->vars($this->data);
        $this->load->view('homeview');
        $selecttable['tablename'] = $this->inventory_model->select_tables();
        $this->load->view('maintenance_view', $selecttable);
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
    }
```

Here is the printscreen in my **view:**

[image]

There is the list of my tables in the database, what I want is I can only show limited tables, for example I just want to show "tbladditional, tblemployees, tblinventorytype". Is there a syntax where I can select a certain table? An equivalent to this syntax

```
"Select * from 'tablename' where 'tablename' = 'something'"
```

It's so confusing so please I really need your help. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function select_tables(){
    $tables = $this->db->list_tables();
    $req_tables = array("tble1", "table2"); //pass your table names as Array
    $tables = array_intersect($tables, $req_tables);
    return $tables;
 }
```

This is the programmatic way I can come with. As CI doesn't have any method to retrieve specific table names.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is great, but is there a way where I can name the array like this $req_tables['tabletype'] because my program is like this: when I add an inventory type, another table is added on my database, all i want is to show only the inventory type tables and not show the "tblemployees" and "tblusers" Is there a way where I can add a table type?

Comment: Because I just wanted to eliminate two tables, "tblemployees" and "tblusers" Can I have a condition like I can unload those tables?

Comment: use `array_diff()` instead of `array_intersect()`.

Comment: It worked. Ah! thank you so much, i've been thinking about putting a condition and many things. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a mixture of Codeigniter and the query result

For example:

```
$table_list = $this->db->list_tables();


foreach($table_list as $tl)
   {
       if(strpos(strtolower($tl),'tbladditional')==true ||
          strpos(strtolower($tl),'tblemployees')==true ||
          strpos(strtolower($tl),'tblinventorytype')==true)
         {
            $query = "Select * from $tl";
        }
}
```